# Only allow access to /admin from a specific domain?

Tags: .htaccess, domain

If I have multiple domains pointing to the same site.

If I have a domain called `admin-domain.com`

I only want to allow `admin-domain.com/admin/`

But disallow `anything-else.com/admin/`

---

Also this needs to be done with `.htaccess`

Also there is no actual `admin` directory, but there are many urls like `...com/admin/products/edit/54` because I am using the CakePHP framework which already uses htaccess for url's like this. I just want to limit admin access to 1 domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the .htaccess file in the Cake webroot directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=admin-domain.com
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This works thank you, is there a way to allow `www.admin-domain.com` also? thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to add the www to this. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://(www\.)?admin-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Just remember, the referring agent can be spoofed. ;-)

Comment: Can you please expand your answer to explain why/how this code addresses the OP's question?